# Obter valor de um input text no javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Colegas, tenho o seguinte cenário:

Tenho um input

```
input type="text" id="myField3" name="myField3" ng-model="selected"/>
```

preciso jogar o conteudo deste input em uma variável no javascript:

```
<script>
var escopo = document.getElementById('myField3').value;
console.log(escopo);
</script>
```

Não me retorna nada no log da variavel. O conteúdo do input está correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece erro de digitaçao (ou o input é gerado em outro momento no fluxo do programa). Não tem `)` no final de `document.getElementById('myField3').value;`

Comment: Você quer pegar esse valor de fora do angularjs, é isso? Porque de dentro ele vai ser atualizado em tempo real no model `selected`.

Comment: Exatamente preciso pegar fora e guardar em uma variável. No input está vindo do angular e está ok. agora preciso que o conteudo desse input jogar para uma variavel no javascript

Comment: Anexa o código com as pastas no Google driver e disponibiliza o link aqui.

Comment: @thiago melhor seria colocar um um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve) aqui mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Usa a propriedade `val` do jquery.

Exemplo:

```
$('#idDoInput').val();//ira retornar o conteudo do input.
```

Comment: Bom dia amigo.Se vc testou por Jquery acredito que tenha cometido um erro de digitação. Bem o seu código está correto.reparei que no input esta faltando um(<).Vou postar um código talvez ajude .

Comment: $(function() {

        $('#botao').click(function () {

            w=document.getElementById("textarea").value;



            alert(w);

        });
    });

Comment: Se continuar com o erro poste o codigo completo

Comment: Amigo ainda permanece. para tentar ilustar, colocando o :
var scope1 = angular.element(document.getElementById('myField3'));
no console.log me aparece da seguinte forma:
[input#myField3.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid, context: input#myField3.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid]
e
[0]
dentro do "[0]" tenho os atributps inclusive o value que preciso

Comment: Rapaz! EU testei teu código aqui e ta 100% ok. Em vez de usar o console.log pra visualizar o valor da variável usa o alart();

Comment: @user10111111 favor não editar o post com comentários, não é essa a finalidade do botão EDITAR. Se a solução não funcionou, deixe um comentário como já fez e tenha paciencia até o autor da resposta lhe responder.

Comment: Thiago, agradeço a atenção mas não é o caso o problema é quando estou passando o conteudo do input até a var do javascript. Isto é necessário pois usarei via JSON.stringify. Em resumo só preciso que o conteudo do input seja lido na variavel do js, e com o comando angular.element(document.getElementById('myField3')); está caindo em uma especie de objeto, que dentro do array[0] tenho o atributo value que preciso

Comment: está vindo corretamento com o conteudo do input
tentei pro exemplo assim mas não deu certo
 angular.element[0](document.getElementById('myField3'));

Comment: exatamente, console.log(escopo)

*escopo 
var escopo = angular.element(document.getElementById('myField3'));

Comment: tentei o escopo[0].value porém veio em branco

Comment: também não deu vem em branco que estranho...logicamente é assim...

Comment: Uma ultima tentativa tenta isso $("input[name='myField3']").each(function () {

                alert($(this).val());
            });